# Spark and Hive table schema out of sync after external overwrite

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, mapr

I'm am having issues with the schema for Hive tables being out of sync between Spark and Hive on a Mapr cluster with Spark 2.1.0 and Hive 2.1.1.

I need to try to resolve this problem specifically for managed tables, but the issue can be reproduced with unmanaged/external tables.

#### Overview of Steps

1. Use `saveAsTable` to save a dataframe to a given table.
2. Use `mode("overwrite").parquet("path/to/table")` to overwrite the data for the previously saved table. I am actually modifying the data through a process external to Spark and Hive, but this reproduces the same issue.
3. Use `spark.catalog.refreshTable(...)` to refresh metadata
4. Query the table with `spark.table(...).show()`. Any columns that were the same between the original dataframe and the overwriting one will show the new data correctly, but any columns that were only in the new table will not be displayed.

#### Example

```python
db_name = "test_39d3ec9"
table_name = "overwrite_existing"
table_location = "<spark.sql.warehouse.dir>/{}.db/{}".format(db_name, table_name)

qualified_table = "{}.{}".format(db_name, table_name)
spark.sql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {}".format(db_name))
```

Save as a managed table

```python
existing_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2)])
existing_df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(table_name)
```

Note that saving as an unmanaged table with the following will produce the same issue:

```python
existing_df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .option("path", table_location) \
    .saveAsTable(qualified_table)
```

View the contents of the table

```python
spark.table(table_name).show()
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

Overwrite the parquet files directly

```python
new_df = spark.createDataFrame([(3, 4, 5, 6)], ["_4", "_3", "_2", "_1"])
new_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(table_location)
```

View the contents with the parquet reader, the contents show correctly

```python
spark.read.parquet(table_location).show()
+---+---+---+---+
| _4| _3| _2| _1|
+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Refresh spark's metadata for the table and read in again as a table. The data will be updated for the columns that were the same, but the additional columns do not display.

```python
spark.catalog.refreshTable(qualified_table)
spark.table(qualified_table).show()
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|  6|  5|
+---+---+
```

I have also tried updating the schema in hive before calling `spark.catalog.refreshTable` with the below command in the hive shell:

```python
ALTER TABLE test_39d3ec9.overwrite_existing REPLACE COLUMNS (`_1` bigint, `_2` bigint, `_3` bigint, `_4` bigint);
```

After running the ALTER command I then run describe and it shows correctly in hive

```python
DESCRIBE test_39d3ec9.overwrite_existing
OK
_1                      bigint
_2                      bigint
_3                      bigint
_4                      bigint
```

Before running the alter command it only shows the original columns as expected

```python
DESCRIBE test_39d3ec9.overwrite_existing
OK
_1                      bigint
_2                      bigint
```

I then ran `spark.catalog.refreshTable` but it didn't effect spark's view of the data.

#### Additional Notes

From the spark side, I did most of my testing with PySpark, but also tested in a spark-shell (scala) and a sparksql shell. While in the spark shell I also tried using a `HiveContext` but didn't work.

```python
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
val hiveObj = new HiveContext(sc)
hiveObj.refreshTable("test_39d3ec9.overwrite_existing")
```

After performing the ALTER command in the hive shell, I verified in Hue that the schema also changed there.

I also tried running the ALTER command with `spark.sql("ALTER ...")` but the version of Spark we are on (2.1.0) does not allow it, and looks like it won't be available until Spark 2.2.0 based on this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19261

I have also read through the spark docs again, specifically this section: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-metastore-parquet-table-conversion

Based on those docs, `spark.catalog.refreshTable` should work. The configuration for `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet` is typically `false`, but I switched it to `true` for testing and it didn't seem to effect anything.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while using spark 2.2.0 in CDH 5.11.x package.

After `spark.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable()` when I issue `spark.read.table().show` no data will be displayed.

On checking I found it was a known issue with CDH spark 2.2.0 version. Workaround for that was to run the below command after the saveAsTable command was executed.

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE qualified_table set SERDEPROPERTIES ('path'='hdfs://{hdfs_host_name}/{table_path}')")

spark.catalog.refreshTable("qualified_table")
```

eg: If your table LOCATION 
is like **hdfs://hdfsHA/user/warehouse/example.db/qualified_table** 
then assign *'path'='hdfs://hdfsHA/user/warehouse/example.db/qualified_table'*

This worked for me. Give it a try. I assume by now your issue would have been resolved. If not you can try this method.

**workaround source:** https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/spark2/2-2-x/topics/spark2_known_issues.html

Comment: Hey @Krish, thanks for the input. I mentioned this under the Additional Notes, I know its a long post :), but running `ALTER` in `spark.sql(...)` is not allowed in Spark 2.1.x. That didn't become available until 2.2.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19261. So it looks like the issue is in both versions, there is just an easier workaround in 2.2.0.

Comment: I was also facing some issue with alter command but it was a different.. I manged using subprocess in python...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520227/how-to-delete-a-particular-month-from-a-parquet-file-partitioned-by-month/57615684#57615684