# How to create an EXTERNAL Spark table from data in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have loaded a parquet table from HDFS into a DataFrame:

`val df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://user/zeppelin/my_table")`

I now want to expose this table to Spark SQL but this must be a persitent table because I want to access it from a JDBC connection or other Spark Sessions.

Quick way could be to call `df.write.saveAsTable` method, but in this case it will materialize the contents of the DataFrame and create a pointer to the data in the Hive metastore, creating another copy of the data in HDFS.

I don't want to have two copies of the same data, so I would want create like an external table to point to existing data.

Answer (score 3):

To create a Spark External table you must specify the "path" option of the DataFrameWriter. Something like this:

```
df.write.
  option("path","hdfs://user/zeppelin/my_mytable").
  saveAsTable("my_table")
```

The problem though, is that it will empty your hdfs path `hdfs://user/zeppelin/my_mytable` eliminating your existing files and will cause an `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.`. This looks like a bug in Spark API...

Anyway, the workaround to this (tested in Spark 2.3) is to create an external table but from a Spark DDL. If your table have many columns creating the DDL could be a hassle. Fortunately, starting from Spark 2.0, you could call the DDL `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to let spark do the hard work. The problem is that you can actually run the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in a persistent table.

If the table is pretty big, I recommend to get a sample of the table, persist it to another location, and then get the DDL. Something like this:

```
// Create a sample of the table 
val df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://user/zeppelin/my_table")
df.limit(1).write.
    option("path", "/user/zeppelin/my_table_tmp").
    saveAsTable("my_table_tmp")

// Now get the DDL, do not truncate output
spark.sql("SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table_tmp").show(1, false)
```

You are going to get a DDL like:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table_tmp` (`ID` INT, `Descr` STRING)
USING parquet
OPTIONS (
  `serialization.format` '1',
  path 'hdfs:///user/zeppelin/my_table_tmp')
```

Which you would want to **change** to have the **original name of the table** and the **path to the original data**. You can now run the following to create the Spark External table pointing to your existing HDFS data:

```
spark.sql("""
  CREATE TABLE `my_table` (`ID` INT, `Descr` STRING)
  USING parquet
  OPTIONS (
    `serialization.format` '1',
    path 'hdfs:///user/zeppelin/my_table')""")
```

Comment: When I tried to `specify "path" option` (in `Overwrite` mode), I didn't get any `SparkException`. But the schema of resulting `Hive` `EXTERNAL` table was incorrect: it collapsed all columns into `col array<string>`

Comment: @y2k-shubham are you using parquet format or csv? If you are using a CSV it is probably a problem with the field separator

Comment: **@Gabriel Avellaneda** I was outputting it in `ORC` format. Looks like it [wasn't just me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201436/). By the way, the straightforward solution was to run a `Hive` `DROP TABLE..` command followed by `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE..` with proper schema.